# Prevent chrome from redirecting to it's own error page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome I like to look at the result headers and see relevant debugging http requests. Chrome doesn't let you see that if the result was a 400 or 500 error because instead it redirects you to a "This page isn’t working" page that they have baked in.

Is there anything in Chrome that allows us to disable this behavior so we can see the actual result with it's headers?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can see everything in `chrome://net-export`.